# Dapper.plus get tablename and key column name from DapperPlusManager

Tags: dapper-plus

I'm using Dapper.Plus with DapperPlusManager to map objects from database.

I map my class like this:

```
DapperPlusManager.Entity<Order>()
 .Key(order => order.OrderID)
 .Table("zzz.customers");
```

I would like to receive the table name and the column name in my dao class. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Dapper Plus](https://dapper-plus.net/)

That is currently impossible (no easy syntax for it)

I recommend you to create an issue here: https://github.com/zzzprojects/Dapper-Plus/issues and link this Stack Overflow post. We will surely try to find something that will meet your requirement.